# how to get the total size in TB of all the buckets available in my project in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am using gcloud version 'Google Cloud SDK 204.0.0' I need to get the total size in tb of all the buckets in my project. I am bound to use cloud SDK version 204.0.0 which is older one. How to get the total volume of one/all my buckets in one project?

Answer (score 4):

`gsutil du` will get you the the sized of all files in all buckets

`gsutil du -s` will get you the sized of each bucket

```
gsutil du -s | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'
```

will get you the sum of all the buckets in bytes

```
gsutil du -s | awk '{s+=$1}END{printf "%.10g TB\n", s/1000000000000}'
```

will get you the sum of all the buckets in TB

**UPD 1** (add power shell version for Windows user):

I am probably butchering it, but here is my attempt to "Google Translate" from awk to PS:

`gsutil du -s | %{ [Decimal]$s+=$_.Split(' ')[0]/1000000000000; } ; Write-Host "$s TB" ; Clear-Variable -Name "s"`

**UPD 2** (add the exponent of 10):

finally you can change `1000000000000` to `1e12`

Comment: I am running this command in windows, and getting below error.
'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: awk is Linux tool. You can use Google Cloud shell and run the command.

Comment: Updated the post.